# setFixedLengthStreamingMode not working for http PUT request to s3

Tags: java, connection, httpurlconnection

I am trying to do a http PUT request to a s3 URL, using HttpURLConnection.
But for some reason setFixedLengthStreamingMode is not working for me. Can someone help ?

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(uploadLocation).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("x-amz-server-side-encryption", CommonConstants.AMZ_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) new File(localFilePath).length());
```

The last statement is not doing anything. If I do a `connection.getContentLength()`, it shows -1. Can someone help ?

edit :
I am actually trying to do this : but it's not working. getting java io exception : stream is closed.

```
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(localFilePath);
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    input.close();
    out.close();
```

Comment: Re your edit, the stack trace is required, but it's really a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpURLConnection.getContentLength()`returns the length off the response, not of the request.

Comment: even in the debugger I don't see setFixedLengthStreamingMode setting fixedContentLength property in the request.

Comment: But does it work when you send the data? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: edited the question. I am getting stream closed error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `BufferedOutputStream` with `setFixedLengthStreamingMode` because in fixed length mode all body must be written into output stream before request. And buffering may prevent it.

To fix your code you can write directly to `OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();`. Or just don't call `setFixedLengthStreamingMode`.